# Append predefined style to a Word bookmark with c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I try to set text and a predefined style to a bookmark. Text is fine, but the style is not set. Whats wrong with this source?:

```
Word.Application word = new Word.Application();

word.Visible = true;
Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open("bookmark.dotx");
doc.Activate();

Word.Paragraph paragraph = doc.Bookmarks["navigatorHeadlineBookmark"].Range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "hello headline";
paragraph.Range.set_Style("navigatorHeadline");
//Debug 
paragraph.Range.Select(); //selects the expected text (hello headline)
Word.Selection selection = word.Selection;
selection.set_Style("navigatorHeadline"); //style is not set :-(
```

Comment: In order to trouble-shoot, put in a line of code:
    paragraph.Range.Select();

And let the code finish with that (if anything follows, comment it out). Where's the selection? Does it contain the text you expect? If you apply the style in the UI to this selection does it do what you expect or does it also fail? You may need to adjust your Range...

Comment: I've edited my source above. paragraph.Range.Select() selects the expected text correct, but set_Style of the selection does not work.

Comment: The next thing I check in such a situation is whether the style name is spelled correctly, keeping in mind it's case-sensitive. And I also test applying it directly to the selection, in the document, as an end-user, just to see if something's weird there.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind is that, if this is a paragraph and not a character style, depending on the settings in Word it might not want to apply to "just characters". This is obscure and the default settings should allow it, but you never know... Unfortunately I won't be at a machine with the full version + dev environment until next week so I can't do any testing or looking up of settings for you until then.

Comment: Hi, after a long time of debugging I found a way out. The bookmark in the bookmark.dotx was formatted as a Hyperlink. If it is format as Standard Text set_style(...) works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hyperlink is a character style, which will override a paragraph style, so that does explain the situation. I'll write up an "Answer" so that others can profit from the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the steps to trouble-shoot that finally led to the answer:
1. First, make sure the bookmark is in the document and contains the correct text/range.
2. Check that the style name is spelled correctly, keeping in mind that Word handles style names as case-sensitive
3. Direct formatting and character styles will override the formatting of a paragraph style.

This last proved to be the reason style formatting was not appearing: the text was formatted with the Hyperlink style. This is a character style, so was overriding the formatting from the style specified in the code.

In this case, the character style must be removed in order to see the formatting from the paragraph style. Programmatically, this can be done EITHER

1. By applying the character style "Default Paragraph Font" to the Range
   *or*
2. By using one of the "clear formatting" methods of the Selection object. Which to choose depends on the exact behavior desired. All formatting can be cleared, all direct formatting can be cleared, or the character style can be cleared (which would give the same result as option 1): `Selection.ClearCharacterStyle`.